# Copy files from one directory into another with path indicated on argv variable array using syscall

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, system-calls

how to copy regular file `t/a/a` `t/a/b`  into `t/b/` directory using POSIX syscall?

with the possibility to copy the same file multiple time if it's indicated as a argument in command line. The last argument is always the destination of the file.

execution: `./copy t/a/a  t/a/a t/a/b   t/b/` or `./copy t/a/a t/a/b t/a/b t/a/b  /t/b/`

This is the setup file

```
   setup () {
        mkdir -p t/a t/b
    echo "XXXX" > t/a/a
    echo "XXXX" > t/b/a
    echo "MMMM" > t/a/b
         }
```

Start of the file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#define BS 512



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {



DIR *dir2;
struct dirent *read2;
struct stat st;
int data;



}
```

Comment: So, what have **you** tried to add to the setup file to solve the problem?

Comment: Open the source file for reading. Create the destination file open for writing. Read from source, write to destination.